# How to make windows 7 auto disable wired connection when wireless connection is made

Tags: networking, windows-7, wireless

I have both connection wired and wireless. I use wired connection for network access

Is there any way that when i connect to wireless connection. the wired connection disconnects until i disconnect the wireless connection

OR

all the traffic goes from wireless gateway and internal sites is disabled etc.

I have tried to manually set the interface metric for both connection ( lower for wireless , higher for wired ) but still network is accessible.

I have also tried these steps in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/247601/make-windows-7-ignore-wifi-when-ethernet-is-available) link by re ordering connections but still im able to access internal websites.

Using Windows 7

Comment: I doubt the interface metric works if that are different networks. Windows will probably just use one connection for internal and the other for external (I'd assume thats the default use case) It could probably be done with scheduled tasks and some scripting/programming. Is that a possibility for you or are you only interested in some setting?

Comment: yes i can make a programming language file and set a schedule would it disable the wired network when the wireless connection is made and enable the wired network once wireless is disconnected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a scheduled task triggered by network connection. That would be

"Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > WLAN-AutoConfig > Operational" Event ID 8001 for connection of a Wireless network.

Based on this event trigger you could run a program/script that disables the network adapter you don't want.
You can either use [devcon.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311272/de?wa=wsignin1.0) ([download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f7dd10-272d-4cd2-896f-9ce67f3e0240/devcon.exe)) for this, which is a microsoft for programmatic device manager access.

The syntax would be

```
devcon disable "pci\ven_<your vendor id>&dev_<your device id>"
```

you can look up these ids in the device manager. Or you can use wmi:

Query the Win32_NetworkAdapter class for your network adapter and call disable in vbscript or powershell or whatever you fancy.

More details on programmatic control of network adapters can be found in [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/13/enabling-and-disabling-network-adapters-with-powershell.aspx)

If you want more control over when this happens (like e.g. you only want it to happen with a specific wireless network at work but not at home) you should always use a script even if you want devcon and just add a few checks before the call.

If you want to enable the network automatically as well the event id for disconnection of a wireless network would be 8003.